# Use wget to download Twitter images specifying size

Tags: python, twitter, wget

I am using the wget library in Python to download images from twitter that I have filtered through hashtags. Twitter gives us the capability to select the size of the image we want to see by appending the size at the end of the URL.

e.g. : https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DzzjbQ5UYAEh5Y8.jpg:medium

This URL in itself can be browsed, but when I try to use the wget command on it( `wget.download(url)` ). I get an error

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

of course when I remove the medium at the end of the URL, I can both browse and download from the link.

Can anyone tell me what we can do to enable downloading the image with size description using wget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Python wget - I've raised it as an issue at https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/issues/26/urls-with-colon-in-path-404

I suggest using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It is a little bit more code, but it works :-)

```
import requests

image = requests.get("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DzzjbQ5UYAEh5Y8.jpg:medium")
if 200 == image.status_code:
    with open("image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image.content)
```